# add attachment pdf android email

Tags: android, email, pdf

The problem is when the file is sent because, is not adding the extension to the file (Pdf)

This is my code to send email:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                try {

                 final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                     android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);                
                     emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                     emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

                     Uri prueba = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.tecnolite); 
                     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, prueba);

                     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviando correo..."));


                 } catch (Throwable t) {
                     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al enviar el correo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                     toast.show(); 
                 }

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An android resource belonging to one package is private to that package and can not be accessed by another process. In this case, the email app can not access your app's resources. You either need to copy the resource into external memory, or implement a `ContentProvider` for the email app to load your stream. This `ContentProvider` would also identify the correct mime-type for your attachment.